# Update ng-model from Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angular application and `textarea` in it:

```
<textarea id="log_text_area" readonly>{{logger}}</textarea>
```

Also i have a `Logger` service which must update this `textarea`.

```
angular.module('app').factory('Logger', [function(){
    var logger = {};

    //
    // Write log
    //
    logger.log = function(log_area, arguments){
        // get current date
        var date = new Date();
        // log message
        var message = '';

        // traverse object and collect log message
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            message += arguments[i] + " ";
        }

        console.log(log_area);

        // check log area
        if (log_area != undefined){
            // log value
            var value = "[" + date + "}] " + message + "\n";
            value += log_area;
            log_area = value;
        }
    };

    // return logger
    return logger;
}]);
```

Now i want to update my textarea from controller:

```
function MyController($scope, Logger) {     
    $scope.logger = '';

    Logger.log($scope.logger, 'Logs Logs Logs');
}
```

But it doesn't update. How to update textarea from `angular` service?

Thank you.

Comment: You're passing `$scope.logger`, a primitive, by value. Overwriting the passed value does nothing to $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your log function return the text only and assign the returned value to your $scope property in the controller.

```
$scope.logger = Logger.Log('log, log log');
```

Or you could call `$scope.$apply();` after the log() call, but approach numero uno is cleaner.

Comment: Yes, i know about $scope.$apply, but i want to update textarea into `Logger` service.

Comment: Services aren't supposed to make changes to a scope directly. Actually I shouldn't have even said the second approach because it's just improper for this reason.